# C++, Up arrow detected as both up and right

Tags: c++, switch-statement, getch

I defined the four arrow keys as such-

```
#define UP_ARROW    72
#define LEFT_ARROW  75
#define DOWN_ARROW  80
#define RIGHT_ARROW 77
```

And the keys are being checked using _getch(), as such

```
char key = _getch();
if (key == 0 || key == -32)
{
    key = _getch();
    switch (key)
    {
    case UP_ARROW:
        //These are functions not relevant to the problem
        //up(1);
    case DOWN_ARROW:
        //down(1);
    case LEFT_ARROW:
        //left(1);
    case RIGHT_ARROW:
        //right(1);

        //Pressing up will print out "test", which should not happen
        printf("test");
    }
}
```

As commented, pressing up will call anything in the RIGHT_ARROW case. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `break;` statement to stop continuation of a switch.

> You can use the break statement to end processing of a particular case
>   within the switch statement and to branch to the end of the switch
>   statement. Without break, the program continues to the next case,
>   executing the statements until a break or the end of the statement is
>   reached. In some situations, this continuation may be desirable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Without `break`, the `case` statements runs all through:

```
case UP_ARROW:
    //up(1);
    break;     //here
case DOWN_ARROW:
    //down(1);
    break;     //and here
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used it once as:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define KB_UP 72
#define KB_DOWN 80
#define KB_LEFT 75
#define KB_RIGHT 77
#define KB_ESCAPE 27


int main()
{
   int KB_code=0;

   while(KB_code != KB_ESCAPE )
   { 
     if (kbhit())
      {
            KB_code = getch();
            printf("KB_code = %i \n",KB_code);

            switch (KB_code)
            {
                case KB_LEFT:
                           //Do something
                break;

                case KB_RIGHT:
                           //Do something                     
                break;

                case KB_UP:
                           //Do something                     
                break;

                case KB_DOWN:
                           //Do something                     
                break;

            }        

      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```